# How to force change state of AccesibilityObject

Tags: .net

I have button control:

```
 Protected Friend WithEvents btnAdd As System.Windows.Forms.Button
```

And I'm trying to change Enable property:

```
Me.btnAdd.Enabled = bEnable
```

Above code executes without any errors but value of Enabled property does not change.

I've noticed that AccesibilityObject.State has strange value (Unavailable or Focusable), and I suppose that this is a problem.

[image: Wrong value]

How can I change this value or detect what is responsible for changing it ?

Comment: The `AccessibilityObject` state changes when you change a Control's properties. It's properties reflect the status of a Control. A Control doesn't usually refuse to be enabled or disabled. Do you have some events that modify this property? Which one? Do some other Control's events set this property? Do you Dispose of it (?) and New() it more than once? Are you sure it's the same Control instance you're looking at here?

Comment: Hi Jimi thanks a lot for your answer. Between these two line exists around ~10k lines of code (unfortunately not mine) I'll check your suggestions.